# Xamarin.forms Schedule Local notifications

Tags: xamarin.forms, localnotification

I follow the documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications about local notifications. I implement it and work perfectly fine. Now my scenario is : user enter `Start Date` , `Repetition time` and `Number of Repetitions` . I need some maybe background service to call this push notifications? Any suggestion maybe to schedule this in the device?

**UPDATE**
I added shared service from this link : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-local-notification-with-repeat-interval-in-xamarin-forms/
And now i don't know how to stop the `Alarm Manager` and  `UILocalNotification` when i send example user entered to send 20 notifications , after 20 notification must stop.

Comment: Hi , do you mean that want to stop the notification before it finishes when new setting coming?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT if user enter 10 times on every 10 minutes. After 10 notification must cancel.

Comment: Okey , we need to count the time each time after task be executed . The number of times can be stored in local , if the time meet the setting , will cancel the schedule your want .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT how to cancel ?

Comment: That means we need to cancel the schedule manually according to another schedule which calculate the time to stop . If not mind adding switch control in Page , that will make customer to determine whether need to close the repeated notification.

Comment: In addition , if setting every 10 minutes to send a local notification,  iOS need to create 10 local notifications . So just setting 10 non-repeating schedule will not need to stop them manually .

Comment: Another solution: Creating schedule one by one . When creating first schedule , you can store the repeated times in the local . The first time sending notification , the repeated times plus 1 . Until to the last time sending notification , the count is 10 . Then later will not send notification and will cancle the schedule also . Could you got that ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT now i'm trying to do that. But don't know how to cancel notification from the code

Comment: **iOS** cancles the schedule according to the `localNotification.UserInfo` , **Android** according to the `intent.SetData` . The left things  is to add logic in the programa .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT can u show me a example code of removing  . I made the logic just need cancel it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `AlarmManager.Cancel`  and `UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelLocalNotification` to stop the schedule local notifications .

**iOS** :

```
void CancleScheduleNotification()
{
    UILocalNotification[] localNotifications= UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduledLocalNotifications;
    //Traverse this array to get the UILocalNotification we want according to the key
    foreach (var localNotification in localNotifications)
    {
        if(localNotification.UserInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("key")).ToString() == "value")
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelLocalNotification(localNotification);
        }
    }
}
```

**Android** :

```
void CancleScheduleNotification()
{
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
    Intent intent = new Intent("LILY_TEST_INTENT");
    intent.SetClass(this, LilyReceiver.class);  
    intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://calendar/calendar_alerts/1"));  

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.NoCreate);  
    if (sender != null){  
        Log.Info("lily","cancel alarm");  
        am.Cancel(sender);  
    }else{  
        Log.Info("lily","sender == null");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: 2021 I don't think this works anymore since oreo. It won't work when the app is closed