# How to schedule notification in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, scheduler, localnotification

I am new to Xamarin forms, I need to add to my app a functionality so that the user can schedule reminders.
For example: Send a notification every Monday and Friday at 5 pm.

I have tried to use Local notifications with this library https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny but I am not happy with the result,
the main problem is that if I plan a notification in 3 hours, and the phone is restarted before that time, the notification never arrives.

await ScheduleLocalNotification(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(180));

Also, handling the schedule with a simple delay doesn't help if you need to plan the same reminder for multiple weeks.

I was wondering if push notifications are needed to achieve this behaviour, or what is the best practice to achieve something like this in general.

Thank you

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62894607/199364) has two links in it that talk about notifications - do either of those links help you?

Answer (score 0):

Please check my [sample Xamarin Forms project on GitHub](https://github.com/shantimohan/ShinySamples). In this you can schedule notifications for a selected date and time. It works even after rebooting your device on Android and iOS.

But I have issues in implementing it on my real project where the MainActivity is not that simple as in the sample project. It works fine on iOS in my real project.